# Changing index in arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, foreach

Good day everyone,

I was tasked to change index in arrays.
here is my code:

```
$file = Storage::get('upload/test.txt');
$lines = explode('\n', $file);
$array = array_map(function($line) {
    return explode(',', $line);
}, $lines);
print_r($array);
```

output is:

Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => john
                [1] => male
                [2] => 20
                [3] => 200
                [4] => 174
            )

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => joe
            [1] => male
            [2] => 24
            [3] => 157
            [4] => 166
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => bea
            [1] => female
            [2] => 18
            [3] => 153
            [4] => 160
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => edd
            [1] => male
            [2] => 30
            [3] => 180
            [4] => 180
        )

)
```

what i need to happen is:

Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => john
                [sex] => male
                [age] => 20
                [height] => 200
                [weight] => 174
            )

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => joe
            [sex] => male
            [age] => 24
            [height] => 157
            [weight] => 166
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => bea
            [sex] => female
            [age] => 18
            [height] => 153
            [weight] => 160
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => edd
            [sex] => male
            [age] => 30
            [height] => 180
            [weight] => 180
        )

)
```

thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an associative array.

```
$newArray = []; // create a new empty array to store your associative arrays.

// Loop through each element in array.
foreach($array as $aPerson) {
  // map each element in array into an associative array.
  $person = [
    "name" => $aPerson[0],
    "sex" => $aPerson[1],
    "age" => $aPerson[2],
    "height" => $aPerson[3],
    "weight" => $aPerson[4]
  ];
  // Add your associative array to your new re-indexed array.
  array_push($newArray, $person);
}
```

I hope this helps.

The following should print the array in the format you want.

```
print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, Like this:

```
$arr =     [
    ['joe','male',24,157,166]
];

 #mind the & pass by refrence
foreach($arr as &$item){
    $item = array_combine(['name','sex','age','height','weight'],$item);
}

print_r($arr);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => joe
            [sex] => male
            [age] => 24
            [height] => 157
            [weight] => 166
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9fda4eaf0532fabfcb44d732624eba06270bb3fd)

Note `array_combine` will blow up if the 2 arrays are not the same size.

You can do this too  (84 bytes)

```
$arr =     [['joe','male',24,157,166]];

$headers = ['name','sex','age','height','weight'];

$arr = array_map(function($item)use($headers){return array_combine($headers,$item);},$arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Same output

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e9b9cacc24d949cc6f89c5bfa8c13ee9c55d5e6)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution will be to create a new array, loop through the current one and add the indexes:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($array as $element) {
    $new_array[] = array(
        'name' => $element[0],
        'sex' => $element[1],
        'age' => $element[2],
        'height' => $element[3],
        'weight' => $element[4]
    );

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: @jediArvin What's happening when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do what you're trying to achieve

```
<?php
$fp = @fopen('upload/test.txt', 'r'); $props = ['name', 'sex', 'age', 'height', 'weight']; $r = [];
if($fp) {
  while(($line = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
    $x = explode(',', $line); $a = [];
    foreach($props as $k => $v){
      $a[$v] = $x[$k];
    }
    $r[] = $a;
  }
  fclose($fp);
}
print_r($r);
?>
```